# JFrame: Can't launch new window

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to learn Java and JFrames. I put together this simple app where the Main class launches the MainGui class. MainGui will contain a bunch of buttons that each does something different (right now it only has the canadaFlagButton). I have no problem getting the window for MainGui to open with the button I created.

However, when I click the canadaFlagButton, it is supposed to launch a new window but instead, nothing happens.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MainGui extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JButton canadaFlagButton;

    MainGui() {

        canadaFlagButton = new JButton("Canada Flag");
        canadaFlagButton.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 50);
        canadaFlagButton.setFocusable(false);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(400, 600);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.add(canadaFlagButton);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getSource()==canadaFlagButton) {
            CanadaFlag window1 = new CanadaFlag();
        }
    }
}

//Can I draw the Canadian flag?
```

This is the CanadaFlag class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class CanadaFlag extends JFrame {

    CanadaFlag() {

        //creating label for maple leaf
        JLabel leafLabel = new JLabel();
        ImageIcon leaf = new ImageIcon("mapleleaf.png");
        leafLabel.setIcon(leaf);
        leafLabel.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        leafLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);    
        JPanel redLeftPanel = new JPanel();
        redLeftPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
        redLeftPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 1000);

        JPanel redRightPanel = new JPanel();
        redRightPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
        redRightPanel.setBounds(1000, 0, 400, 1000);

        JPanel whiteMiddlePanel = new JPanel();
        whiteMiddlePanel.setBackground(Color.white);
        whiteMiddlePanel.setBounds(400, 0, 600, 1000);
        whiteMiddlePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setSize(1400, 1000);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.add(redLeftPanel);
        this.add(redRightPanel);
        this.add(whiteMiddlePanel);
        whiteMiddlePanel.add(leafLabel);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. An application should only have a single main JFrame. If you need other windows then you would typically use a JDialog.
2. Swing was designed to be used with layout manager. If you are trying to learn Swing then check out the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working example.

> it is supposed to launch a new window but instead, nothing happens

You never add the `ActionListener` to the button.

```
canadaFlagButton.addActionListener( this );
```

The tutorial also has a section on `How to Use Buttons` that contains a working example. I suggest you keep a reference to the tutorial for examples of all Swing basics.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the ActionListener! I'll keep that link bookmarked looks super helpful.

Comment: @SushiCode, glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark (beside the answer) so people know the problem has been solved.